# Why does an unblocked TCP/IP port appear to be listening from one server but not from another?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, port-forwarding, tcp, tcpip

I have Oracle VirtualBox on my Windows 10 machine (we'll call "hoster"). I have two linux VMs which are getting the same IP address (despite my efforts to give them different IP addresses). I tried changing the `/etc/network/interface` file. But they get the same IP address.

I have configured port forwarding in the settings of these VMs in the Oracle VirtualBox "Network Adapter" settings. This way I can connect to them with unique IP addresses with Putty from my Windows 10 machine.

When I do this from each Linux machine, I get different results:

```
nmap -p 8140 1.2.3.4
```

Instead of `1.2.3.4`, I am using the IP address that was configured for one server in the port forwarding/network adapter settings. This is the IP address I use to connect to the server with Putty.

From the Linux VM guest server that has the IP addresss `1.2.3.4`, I see port `8140` is "Open" (and thus listening). From the other Linux VM guest server, I see port `8140` is "Closed" and thus not filtered/blocked.

I tried to use this `telnet 1.2.3.4 8140`, but I got connection refused from the other server. (This telnet command worked from the `1.2.3.4` server itself.)

What should I do to get consistent nmap results? I did not even realize this scenario was possible.

Update on 3/4/19:  I tried *many* different network adapter settings.  The problem remained reproducible.  I cannot even document the number of different settings that I tried.

Update on 3/5/19:  My problem is consistent with IP addresses on the Linux guest VMs "resolving" (despite me using actual IP addresses and not FQDNs) to 127.0.0.1.  The results of nmap, SSH, and ssh-keyscan commands are all the same no matter what remote IP address I use as a respective argument.  The result of my nmap, SSH, and ssh-keyscan commands is the same as if I used 127.0.0.1.  I have heard of DNS resolving incorrectly.  I do not know why Linux guest VMs would have IP addresses resolve to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Which network interface type did you choose in VM settings in VirtualBox?

Comment: Can you update this description with unique identifiers and IP addresses (even fake ones like 1.2.3.4)?  For example: Windows 10 machine might be called 'hoster', and the two VMs might be called 'vm1' and 'vm2'.  This will help potential answerers build a picture of what is going on, and to understand where IP addresses are different or the same.